# Is there any driver that supports Sybase ASE's Stored Procedures in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, sap-ase

All support I've seen so far is for SQL Anywhere, and sadly, I'm locked to use Sybase ASE 15.5 as well as the Cluster Edition.

All this comes because although I can add SPs to my Entity Model (through Function Import), when I call said SP, it returns nothing, and in the Function Import Window, I can't get the column information because it throws a "System.NotSupportedException".

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1, Sybase ASE 15.5, the SDK 15.5.0.1000 and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue. So, we choose to go with Progress Data Direct Provider

Comment: did you find any code samples on how to set this up? I'm struggling with the web.config settings for 4.2 at the moment.